# What does a ArgumentNullException in Unity 3D + MRTK based project during deployment mean and how to solve it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mrtk

I'm in the midst of upgrading our Unity 2018.3 + [MRTK](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/README.html) project to Unity 2019.4. I've already encountered several issues while upgrading and thought I'll do a simple Unity 2019.4 + MRTK based application which simply consists of a cube placed in scene in order to better understand what's happening.

I've created a new 3D project, enabled the new [XR plugin](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/XR.html#:~:text=Unity%20has%20developed%20a%20new,full%20use%20of%20its%20features.), added MRTK 2.4 to the scene, set the active profile in MRTK to `DefaultXRDSKConfigurationProfile` and added a cube. Build settings are the following:

[image: build settings]

The project build a visual studio solution which compiles and also let me deploy it to a HoloLens. However, VS 2019 shows an error `DEP6701: Bootstrapping failed with unexpected error: ArgumentNullException - Value cannot be null. Error Parameter name: projectUniqueName [0x80004003]`.

The error is shown in Visual Studios error list when I deploy the application to the HoloLens. Why does it occur and how do I get "rid" of it?

**EDIT 1:** Added player settings:

[image: basic player settings]

Comment: Try uninstalling the app first if it was previously installed, then try deploying again. Could you also show your player settings (in particular the Project name)

Comment: Unfortunately, uninstalling the app from the HoloLens doesn't change anything. The error still shows up after stopping the application. I'll add the player settings to the original post in a second.

Comment: So wait the deployment actually works and this error shows only after stopping your app on the lens (debug mode)? Because if this was the case I wouldn't worry about it ^^

Comment: The deployment works, but this error and other warnings (Unity editor itself prints warnings about deprecated methods in com.unity.xr.windowsmr and missing/not valid scripts for a "Sphere" in "scene ''" and "_PlaneThatCallsIntoPlugin") is bugging me a lot and I want to understand what's actually happening (or not).

Comment: Don't worry about warnings coming from MRTK .. if scripts are missing it sounds odd though, this probably shouldn't happen but might be related to different target platforms. (Examples) If deployment works then apparently there are no severe compiler errors. Are running BuildAndRun or do you build and deploy as a separate step directly via VisualStudio?

Comment: I usually build the solution and hit the run button afterwards.

Comment: That runs it in Debug .. but it includes deploying it to the lens. Usually you would first say `Build -> Build Solution` and then `Build -> Deploy`

Comment: Okay, this actually stops VS from bringing up the error.